# finding maximum perimeter of a triangle

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

So, here we are given task to find maximum perimeter of a triangle with a given base  $a$ and given vertical angle $x$ , now how should I proceed in given problem. It's confusing me!

Now supposing triangle is $\Delta ABC$ now $BC=a$ and angle $\angle CAB$ is $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "vertical angle" in this context? Can you upload and link a picture?

Comment: I am not sure but I think its angle opposite to base side

Comment: You are likely to be able to get any perimeter value you want with these constraints regardless of the values of 'a' and 'x', unless you can provide more information and clarity on what the question is asking.

Comment: there is no "base" side unless you mean either the unequal side in an isosceles triangle or the side with length $\,a\,$ that you want to pick up and call it that way. Vertical angle is undefined in your question and unless you can clear out the question seems to be ill-posted.

Comment: The meaning seems to be clear. We hve $\triangle ABC$, with $BC=a$ and $\angle $CAB=x$. We want to maximize perimeter.

Comment: Edited now thanks Andre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\triangle ABC$. If $\angle A$ is the angle opposite to the base side $BC$, (and if that is what you meant by vertical angle) then both $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ is from the range from $0$ to $\pi- x$.

If we denote $\angle B$ as y, then $\angle C$ equals $\pi - x - y$. The lengths of $AB$ and $AC$ are

$$
AB=\frac{a \sin \angle C}{\sin \angle A} = \frac{a \sin (x+y)}{\sin x}\\
AC=\frac{a \sin \angle B}{\sin \angle A} = \frac{a \sin y}{\sin x}
$$

Therefore, we have to find the y that maximises the perimeter

$$a+\frac{a \sin (x+y)}{\sin x}+\frac{a \sin y}{\sin x}.$$

And since $a$ and $x$ are given constants, the problem becomes finding y that maximises $\sin(x+y) + \sin y = f(y)$.

Differentiate this $f(y)$ with respect to y,
$$f'(y) = \cos(x+y) + \cos y = 2 \cos (\frac{x}{2}+y)\cos(\frac{x}{2})$$

Solving $f'(y)=0$, we get
$$\begin{align}
\cos(\frac{x}{2}+y) =& 0\\
\frac{x}{2}+y =& \frac{\pi}{2}\\
y =& \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{x}{2}\\
\end{align}$$

And one can check this $y$ gives a maximum perimeter. The remaining is about substituting this y back to the perimeter formula above.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\Delta ABC$. If $∠A$ is the angle opposite to the base side $BC$, (and if that is what you meant by vertical angle) then both $∠B$ and $∠C$ is from the range from $0$ to $\pi−x$.

If we denote $∠B$ as $y$, then $∠C$ equals $π−x−y$. The lengths of $AB$ and $AC$ are

$AB=\arcsin ∠C \sin ∠A = \arcsin (x+y) \sin xAC = \arcsin ∠B \sin ∠A= \arcsin y 
\sin x$
Therefore, we have to find the $y$ that maximises the perimeter

$a+ \arcsin(x+y) \sin x+ \arcsin y \sin x$.
And since $a$ and $x$ are given constants, the problem becomes finding $y$ that maximises $\sin(x+y)+\sin y=f(y)$.

Differentiate this $f(y)$ with respect to $y$,
$$f′(y)=\cos(x+y)+\cos y=2\cos(x^2+y)\cos(x^2)$$
Solving $f′(y)=0$, we get
$$\cos(x^2+y)=x^2+y=y=\pi^2−x^2$$
And one can check this $y$ gives a maximum perimeter. The remaining is about substituting this $y$ back to the perimeter formula above